is there any way to blur only area on images in bulk in irfan view
I need to blur a little rectangle in the centre in each of 300 photos. how can I blur that area in Irfan view or is there any other software to do that?

It can be done with ImageMagick - see details on this StackOverlow question.

If all the images are the same size, and the rectangle is the same size, you could use the "watermark" feature.
Here is a screen capture of the series of windows you need to use inside
File > Batch Conversion/Rename

Then you choose a transparent PNG file with a rectangle you want to place.
But this is not a real "blur". This could add a solid rectangle or shape.

To properly "blur" or maybe "pixelate" you need to use some other software like Gimp.
Look at some tutorials that use a Plug-in called Bimp.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=batch+action+Gimp

Always backup your original files before doing any batch processing.

tysm, Ill try to do what I want using GIMP

I looked through tutorials but none of them says that I can blur specific area , only the whole image

@АшаАнв You can blur a specific area in GIMP if you make a selection first.  however, I'm not sure if that action can be automated with the Bimp plugin.
